# How to clear/ set a value to null/undefined in parse

Tags: android, parse-platform, illegalargumentexception

I have 3 columns in my Parse class, FOOD1, FOOD2 and FOOD3.
it is optional for the user if they choose 0,1,2 or 3 Foods they like, i save the foods in these columns. This process will be repeated.

For every loop i want to set all these fields on null/undefined so i can simply see if they choose something after selection.
But when one of the fields eg. FOOD1 is filled in the database, i cant clear the value of it.

i tried:

```
 final ParseQuery queryusername = ParseQuery.getQuery("Usernames");
                queryusername.whereContains("names",db.getUsername());
                try {
                    ParseObject p = queryusername.getFirst();

                    System.out.println("parseobject:"+p);
                    //make fields empty
                    p.put("Food1",null); //Error
                    p.put("Food2",null);
                    p.put("Food3",null);
}catch(){}
```

the error is:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: value may not be null.
```

how can i clear the field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Parse object](http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-Android/api/) provides remove().  Pass it the key to remove, e.g.

```
p.remove("Food1");
p.remove("Food2");
p.remove("Food3");
```

Comment: Hey I tried the remove code but for some reason it's not working , anyone else having this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Parse SDK has checks for null.
From the [source](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-Android/blob/master/Parse/src/main/java/com/parse/ParseObject.java#L2981)

`/**
   * Add a key-value pair to this object. It is recommended to name keys in
   * <code>camelCaseLikeThis</code>.
   *
   * @param key
   *          Keys must be alphanumerical plus underscore, and start with a letter.
   * @param value
   *          Values may be numerical, {@link String}, {@link JSONObject}, {@link JSONArray},
   *          {@link JSONObject#NULL}, or other {@code ParseObject}s. value may not be {@code null}.
   */`

Why do you need to set it to NULL? You can always use empty **String** or some constant **integer** or finally **JSONObject.NULL**. 
Or use p.remove as in the answer by @danh

Answer (score 0):

The answer of https://stackoverflow.com/users/294949/danh works. You must save the object:

```java
    p.remove("Food1");
    p.remove("Food2");
    p.remove("Food3");
    try {
            p.save();
    } 
    catch (ParseException e) {
    }
```